# Mailboxer with rails 4 tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

Is there a tutorial for using mailboxer with rails 4? Or does someone have some of their code they could share with me. I guess I'm a bit of a newbie but I feel the documentation even with the examples really needs some sort of tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial explains everything, make sure you have devise all set up and running properly before you go through the steps in this tutorial, it's make things easier to understand.
Also, you will see a conversions controller *not model!, you have to generate that yourself, mailboxer takes care of the model part for you.

http://jamestansley.com/2014/02/22/customizing-the-mailboxer-ruby-gem-2/

Comment: That's not actually a good tutorial for a beginner with Rails 4. LOTS of deprecations and as per the guy who wrote it: "3. What version of Rails are you using? This was tested on 3.2.16." That said it's really the only tutorial on the net for setting up Mailboxer. (Which means it's probably time for me to write one.)

Comment: Yes but I'm using rails 4 and had no problems following it and figuring the rest out on my own or asking here on SO. Of course, it'd be great if you wrote one, much better and less hassle ;)

Comment: And so I shall! I think I'm pretty good with rails by now, but that guide gave me a headache. :)

Comment: did you end up writing one?